# Prove that every element of Hom$_\Bbb{Z}(A, C)$ has order dividing gcd$(m, n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ and $C$ be abelian groups while $m$ and $n$ are integers such that $ma = 0$ and $nc = 0$ for all elements $a \in A$ and $c \in C$. Prove that every element of Hom$_\Bbb{Z}(A, C)$ has order dividing gcd$(m, n)$.

**My proof:**
Showing that the order $z$ of a map $f \in $ Hom$_\Bbb{Z}(A, C)$ divides gcd$(m, n)$ amounts to showing that $z \vert m$ and $z\vert n$ are true. For some integer $z$ and map $f$, $zf$ will denote a pointwise addition $$\underbrace{f+f+\cdots+f}_{\text{$z$ times}}$$
Let's assume that $z\vert m$ is not true, and that $m = zp + r$, where $p, r \in \Bbb{R}$ and $0 <r<z$. Then, for some $a \in A$ $$ma = \underbrace{a + a+ \cdots +a}_{\text{$m$ times}} = (zp + r)a = 0\in A$$
$$f(ma) = f((zp+r)a) = f((zp)a + ra) = f((zp)a) + f(ra) = 0\in C$$  Focusing our attention on $f((zp)a)$, we have $$f((zp)a) = f(\underbrace{a + a+ \cdots +a}_{\text{$zp$ times}})= \underbrace{f(a) + f(a) +\cdots+f(a)}_{\text{$zp$ times}} = (zp)f(a)$$ Since $z$ is the order of $f$, we know that $zf(a)$ must be $0 \in C$. It follows that $(zp)f(a)$ is also $0$. We are now left with $$f((zp)a) + f(ra) = 0 + f(ra) = 0 \implies f(ra) = 0$$ Similar to how we rewrote $f((zp)a)$, $f(ra) = rf(a) = 0$. The contradiction here is that we originally claimed that $z$ was the order of $f$, but now we see that $r < z$ and thus $r$ must've been the order of $f$. Hence, $r = 0$ and $z \vert m$ is true. $z\vert n$ can be shown similarly. $\square$

Please provide feedback on my proof and tell me about any other approaches to the problem.

Comment: For a more positive and direct proof, you can just observe $(m f)(x) = f(m x) = 0$ and $(n f)(x) = n f(x) = 0$.

Comment: So $m$ and $n$ are either equal to or multiples of the order of $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is nothing but extension of @Daniel's comment above:*

Let $f:A \to C$ be a group homomorphism. Then for every $a\in A,$ we have
$$(mf)(a)=f(ma)=f(0)=0$$ and $$(nf)(a)=nf(a)=0.$$ Either of these relations shows that $f$ is an element of finite order in $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,C)$. Also, if $d$ is the order of $f$, then $d| m$ and $d|n$.

(Your argument is also fine, except that you didn't prove every element of $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,C)$ is of finite order. You need to make sure of it first, and then go ahead.)